# Background-Image not working in Firefox

Tags: css, background-image, sprite

Working on my website, I have made a row of 5 little squares, that use the 'background-image' and 'background-position' properties, using a spritesheet of social icons to create a list of external links. Working locally, this technique works fine on every browser I have tested. However, when the site is live, the images show up in all browsers with the exception of Firefox. Here's some example code:

HTML:

```
<div class='icon' id='icon1'></div>
```

CSS

```
.icon{
background-image: url(assets/socialicons.png);  
}
#icon1{
background-position:0px 0px;    
}
#icon1:hover{
background-position:250px 0px;  
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

As of 25th Jan, this ussue has been solved. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Can you set up a http://jsfiddle.net please

Comment: How can we reproduce this issue? please let us know

Comment: The site I'm working on is finmoorhouse.com/contact, this is where the issue resides.

Comment: I'm not seeing any icon divs on that webpage

Comment: @Imaginate I think this is the issue. May I ask what browser you are using?

Comment: @Imaginate So the issue is not Firefox-specific. Any ideas as to how to solve this?

Comment: I'm not seeing any html or css like what you have above, where are the icons supposed to be?  Can't troubleshoot what I can't see:)

Comment: @Imaginate They are here: http://finmoorhouse.com/contact/socialicons.png

Comment: Your footers not showing up on the page at all, it's cut off at the bottom.  Your html is out of whack, you're missing an end div tag.  Check your [validation](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffinmoorhouse.com%2Fcontact%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: Ok, I've fixed that problem but the issue persists. Check out finmoorhouse.com/contact-test

Comment: Still can't see the footer at all in Chrome, however in Firefox, the top is peeking out and it looks like your icons are working

Comment: Works fine in Chrome AND FF here.

Comment: @Imaginate what does 'the top is peeking out' mean, and does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You have errors. The W3C validator says there's a missing `>` in line 96; that may account for the differences between browsers. Different browsers handle errors differently!

Comment: @MrLister I am aware of that, but, looking at the code, it seems fine. I can't find what it's talking about.

Comment: @Fin Moorhouse PM me and I'll send you a screenshot

Comment: @FinMoorhouse If you look at the source, it has `<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="SEND"` on line 95, and that should have a `>` after it.

Comment: @Imaginate sorry for not getting back to you. Thanks to Mr Lister for spotting this problem, has solved a lot on the W3C validator but the main issue still persists.

Comment: Just to remind everyone, nobody has come up with a definitive solution, so this thread remains unsolved. Thanks for all the help so far!